# Обьединение запроса в Spring Data-Jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-jpa

Использую в проекте Spring Data-Jpa и появилась необходимость использовать метод `saveAll()` (у меня CRUD интерфейс который я наследую от `JpaRepository`). Сейчас, когда я вызываю этот метод, в консоле я вижу что Hibernate делает отдельный запрос для каждого Entity, а я хочу что бы он делал это в одном запросе. Нашёл [эту](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-batch-inserts) статью, но тут используют Spring Boot, я настраиваю Spring через XML.

Answer (score 0):

Можно добавить property `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` для конфига Hibernate. Подробнее можно прочитать [тут](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_batch_processing.htm) или [тут](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-hibernate-batch-insert-update).

Comment: Добавил в EntityManagerFactory это, но не работает
`<entry key="#{T(org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings).STATEMENT_BATCH_SIZE}" value="50"/>`

Comment: Гляда на использование, значение данного поля используется в построении SessionFactory и в диалектах для разных СУБД. Проверьте, поддерживает ли драйвер для субд batch processing. Вообще есть сомнения, что данная настройка касается EntityManagerFactory, скорее SessionFactory. Попробуйте настроить SessionFactory на установление данного значения. Можете проверить потом в дебаге, сработало ли.